# Webpack serve not using the path in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Trying to understand Webpack

webpack --version

webpack 5.39.1

webpack-cli 4.7.2

webpack-dev-server 3.11.2

I understand webpack-dev-server doesn't like webpack 5. So instead of playing around with versions, I want to use webpack serve.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
}
```

If I run
webpack
it generates dist\bundle.js

If I run
webpack serve
it serves bundle.js from the root, not from the path.
So my HTML file can't find it.
Any ideas what I'm missing?

app.js:

```
document.write("Hello");
console.log('App loaded');
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit, adding console logs.

```
webpack serve
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\ProgrammingProjects\Webpack\2-webpack-config
i ｢wdm｣: asset bundle.js 376 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 432 bytes 3 modules
modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ 320 KiB
  modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ 299 KiB 11 modules
  modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 20.9 KiB
    modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/*.js 6.48 KiB 5 modules
    modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/*.js 9.33 KiB 3 modules
    modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/clients/*.js 5.11 KiB 2 modules
modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack/ 16.1 KiB
  modules by path C:/...AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 1.42 KiB
    C:\...AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\hot\emitter.js 75 bytes [built] [code generated]
    C:\...AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\hot\log.js 1.34 KiB [built] [code generated]
  C:\...AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\hot/ sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes [built] [code generated]
  C:\...AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\events\events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
./app.js 128 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 560 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: It's working in mine. Make sure you have `webpack serve`, `webpack-cli` and `webpack-dev-server` installed. And if its not working then share logs from your terminal.

Comment: I added the console logs. I found I can use output publicPath: "/dist/", but if I do that, the dist/bundle.js still does not get updated. Webpack serve will send an updated /dist/bundle.js to the web server, but not update the saved one.